# Odoo 14 Installation : Connection to the database failed and no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, odoo, pgadmin, odoo-14

I am trying to install the openERP Odoo 14 on macOS Catalina version 10.15.7. I have installed python3, postgreSQL, pgAdmin4 just as demanded and cloned odoo 14 from [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git) but when I type this command `python3 odoo-bin -d odoo14` which should create the database, it didn't work whereas it gives this error saying Connection to the database failed and no password supplied:

```
2021-04-15 11:46:20,236 79206 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 14.0                            
2021-04-15 11:46:20,236 79206 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons', '/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/14.0', '/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/addons'] 
2021-04-15 11:46:20,237 79206 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default 
2021-04-15 11:46:20,262 79206 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odoo-bin", line 8, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/cli/command.py", line 61, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 178, in run
    main(args)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 142, in main
    odoo.service.db._create_empty_database(db_name)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 99, in _create_empty_database
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 675, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 558, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 626, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I am using python3 of the system not a virtual environment.
Could anyone please help me figure out what's wrong and get Odoo 14 working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the Odoo documentation, [install > Mac OS](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/setup/install.html#mac-os).

Comment: Thanks @Kenly but in fact, I was following that link till when typing `sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER`, it show that this command createuser: command not found even though I search on the net and it does exist!!

Comment: Did you try to create the user with a tool like [pg admin](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/setup/install.html#postgresql).

Comment: @Kenly I have installed pgadmin but I didn't create any user with it.

Comment: Try to create a user with the same name as your Unix login, to be able to connect to the database without password.

Answer (score 0):

When you first install PostgreSQL on MacOS with `brew` it creates a db user
with the same name as your **MacOS user with no password**.

Can you try launching with these flags?

```
python3 odoo-bin -d odoo14 --db_user=yourusername --db_password=False
```